# Unable to Complete SSL Connection with Certificate and Python Request

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

i'm having this problem for days now, and can't figure out what exactly is wrong. I'm trying to connect to a server that requires authentication with digital certificates, and have done this before with the requests library in the following manner:

```
cert = (f'/path/to/cert.crt', f'/path/to/cert.open.key')
response = requests.get(url_server,cert=cert,headers=headers,proxies=proxies)
```

At first, i received the following error: `[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'`. I imagined it had something to do with the server certificate, because i have used the same client certificate to log in other sites before. For testing purposes, i made the call with `verify=False` in order to ignore any problems with the server certificate, and got this:

```
SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE] sslv3 alert bad certificate (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

I tried to point the verify to a folder with the cert chain files (root and intermediate), and also to the certBundle file when the previous didn´t work, as documented in https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification, but to no avail. I'm lacking knowledge about the minutia of the handshake process and therefore can´t think in any new way to debug this issue. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You identified the first error correctly as related to the server certificate. The second error means that the server is not accepting the client certificate. Unfortunately it is not clear why, since it is not clear what the expectations of the server regarding the client certificates are and how your client certificate tries to meet the expectations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What bothers me with this problem is the fact that when i try to log in with the browser everything works as expected, but when i try to do "the same" thing with requests it fails. I don´t know what the browser is doing with my client certificate that i am unable to do with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The client certificate was lacking the certificate chain (for the client). Using Wireshark i intercepted the packages and compared what the browser was sending with the packages requests was sending. This allowed me to see that the browser automatically inserts the client certificate chain to the certificate, while requests doesn't.